# Display only banners for a specific month

Tags: views

I need to create a View that will display a banner **for a specific month (regardless of the year).**

I create a field for that called, DisplayMonth, which holds an integer (so September is 9).

I would like for that banner image to change automatically for 2014. **Any september month, no matter what year**, it will display the record with DisplayMonth = 9.

Answer (score 1):

Create a contextual filter against the field that holds the month number. Provide a default value of PHP code:

```
return date('n');
```

Now only those nodes will display in September that have 9 as the month number.

Comment: The date() function without the timestamp always returns the current date: `return date('n');` will work fine.